# S3 Birectional Replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

In order to enable S3 bi-directional replication , should I perform put bucket replication on both buckets and ensure that the role that I am using can support bi-directional replication?

```
aws s3api put-bucket-replication --bucket east-bucket --replication-configuration  file://replication-east.json

aws s3api put-bucket-replication --bucket west-bucket --replication-configuration  file://replication-west.json
```

Comment: If i do put-bucket-replication on both buckets similar to above , what would happen

Comment: I haven't tried to do this but if you decide to try it then please tell us what happens.

Comment: @jarmod I tried it and it works fine. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Interesting, it does work. I wonder how it handles merges, if at all.

Comment: @jarmod there's no conflict management.  This works because there's no cascading -- objects replicated in are never replicated out again.